# hashmaps getting key by distinct value

Tags: hashmap, integer, key, key-value

Example hashmap value

```
3 - 2
20 - 2
4 - 2
5 - 3
```

How to get key value `5` because it has unique/distinct value of `3` different from other with value of `2`

Im trying to looping and comparing previous value still working on this.
Is there a way to get this without loop because I have loop already and I hope no loop solution to make code run faster.

> UPDATE
> I tried doing below just removing directly and not adding in hashmap but still i get wrong result
>
> ```js
> int i = a.length - 1;
> while (a.length > 1) {
>   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
>   System.out.println(a[i]);
>   System.out.println(ArrayUtils.contains(a, a[i]));
>   if (ArrayUtils.contains(a, a[i])) {
>     // Do some stuff.
>     a = ArrayUtils.removeElement(a, a[i]);
>   }
>   i--;
> }
> ```

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? Your code snippet looks like Java code, but it's enclosed in a snippet container for JavaScript, which is confusing. Also, your Java code shows an array but you're asking about a HashMap, again confusing. Anyway, to try to answer your question, no, you can't directly lookup a value in a map, that's what the key is for. And what if there are multiple entries for the given value?